# Redirect returns a bad constructor error

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference

What's wrong with this code?

```
public PageReference goodResponse() {
    PageReference fwdMessage = new PageReference(Page.TLResponsePage);
    fwdMessage.setRedirect(true);
    return fwdMessage;
}
```

The `TLResponsePage` is there and everything. I'm calling this method from another method that returns another PageReference. Should all be good, but instead I get this error:

```
Constructor not defined: [System.PageReference].<Constructor>(System.PageReference)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your declaration to:

```
PageReference redirect = Page.MyPage;
```

You can't pass a `PageReference` into the `PageReference` constructor, which you are trying to do.

Comment: So simple. Thank-you. And if I have some global variables in that method's class, should I be able to refer to them in `TLResponsePage` by their name? Because that returns this error: `"Unknown property 'ParentClass.varName'",`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. Maybe worth a separate question? You can set parameters with `redirect.getParameters().put(key, value)`.